# How convert Matrix to Rotate?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Example:

```
Value of Matrix of TextFrame:
MValueA=0.707110047340393
MValueB=0.707110047340393
MValueC=-0.707110047340393
MValueD=0.707110047340393
MValueTX=-11116.84375
MValueTY=-281.0703125
```

How convert Matrix to Rotate?
Used code.

Comment: In other words, you need to get the rotation angle from the matrix.  Am I right?

Comment: Is my solution ok for you?

Answer (score 2):

For the case when A, B, C and D are non-zero and (A = D) and (C = -B) the Matrix can be converted to rotation by angle *α* and resizing with the rate *k* as follows:

[image]

The VBA Code:

```
If (A < 0#) Then Shift = Math.Sgn(B) * 180# Else Shift = 0#
Angle = Math.Atn(B / A) * 180 / 3.14159265358979 + Shift
Ratio = Math.Sqr(A * A + B * B)
Path.Rotate Angle, True, False, False, False, aiTransformCenter
Path.Resize 100# * Ratio, 100# * Ratio, True, False, False, False, 1, aiTransformCenter
```

In your example Angle = 45, Ratio = 1.00000462

Comment: Yes.  This is just a proportional resize with no rotation

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this...

The quickest method is to translate, scale, or rotate an object while duplicating it. To duplicate an object in Windows, hold down the 'alt' key*. The transformation and duplication can then be repeated by pressing CTRL + D.

For greater precision, select a transformation tool from the toolbox and press enter. A dialogue should then appear, allowing you to enter numerical values, and has a 'copy' button. Again, once the dialogue has closed, you can press CTRL + D to repeat.

The Blend tool can 'step' objects, which also has an option for rotating objects to match a path.

The 'Actions' palette can record and playback multiple transformations.

Illustrator supports a number of languages for scripting, and this offers the most flexible solution but is generally more time consuming to learn and set up.